# html agility package

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

i am trying to retrieve a certain response, i have the request and im loading it into the html document this is the code:

HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("Some URL");

the problem is that upon accessing the url in my browser and parsing the same url using the form above, im retrieving almost the same page, but some content is missing. this might be due to  the time needed to retrieve the values(POSSIBLY), what can i do inorder to make sure i retrieve the same results as in the browser! this is top urgent and vital! 
Please ASSIST ME!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the source HAP-parsed source with the source in your browser.

```
File.WriteAllText(*some path to file*, hw.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```